# Is it possible to decompile Web Assembly (wasm) files to a specific programming language?

Tags: webassembly

Currently most programming languages, can compile to WebAssembly (officially or through an external package).

So I'm wondering... is it possible to decompile the web assembly file? So we can have the code written in one language that can compile to `.wasm`, and decompile it using another language? And then, generate `.java`, `.js`, `.py`, `.go` and etc, from the `.wasm` file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no WebAssembly disassemblers that I am aware of at the moment. One significant obstacle to this is that a great deal of information is discarded in the compilation process. The languages you are interested in (JavaScript, Java, Python, Go) have constructs like strings, classes, structs, etc ... none of which exist at the WebAssembly level. Furthermore, function and variables names are not (typically) present in the resulting WebAssembly module.

While you could create a tool that would 'translate' a WebAssembly module into a Java, Python, Go or JavaScript program that when executed it exhibited the correct behaviour, it would look nothing like the original program that was compiled to WebAssembly.

Comment: Thanks @ColinE, that answer my question. My use case tho is having one code, and using it everywhere, without caring how the generated code looks like. I'll try to do some investigation regarding to that.

Comment: @KadoBOT that exactly the concept of Virtual Machines. Some of those can be embedded in other programs. Also some of them execute WebAssembly.

Comment: this is incorrect. go has no classes and there is no decompiler for a binary it produces.

Answer (score 21):

There is a converter from webassembly binaries to C.

https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/tree/master/wasm2c

As written in the other answer it will not look anything of the original source file, but at least it should be able to transfer the logic to C which then again also could be used with other languages by wrapping it into a library.

Comment: How hard would it be to reverse engineer an application from the generated code?

Answer (score 6):

@KadoBOT you can use wasm-decompile.exe to decompile your wasm file
https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt