# Can I decompile a WebAssembly module?

Tags: assembly, webassembly, decompiling, decompiler

Is it possible to decompile a WebAssembly module like:

https://github.com/blinkcard/blinkcard-in-browser/blob/master/resources/basic/BlinkCardWasmSDK.wasm

Answer (score 1):

You can, but at the momently only to C, with something like this: https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/tree/main/wasm2c

In the compilation process, a lot of the data that is to make source code, such as variable types or classes are stripped out, meaning reversing the process is very difficult.

While there potentially could be a tool to "translate" WebAssembly modules to different, higher level languages, it would not be anywhere near the actual source code that was compiled.

Source: [Is it possible to decompile Web Assembly (wasm) files to a specific programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541790/is-it-possible-to-decompile-web-assembly-wasm-files-to-a-specific-programming)

Comment: Thanks. I already tried wasm2c. It does not work with this use case.